# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

Prove that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$

**Attempt:**

I don't really understand the meaning g(x) is bounded.

I did this problem in general way.

I have $\lim f(x) = 0$ and 
$$\lim f(x)\cdot g(x) \iff \lim f(x)\cdot \lim g(x) \iff 0\cdot \lim g(x) = 0$$

Please check for me if I did right and correct me if I did wrong
thanks

Comment: This link gives a solution you can check against: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754938/if-f-is-bounded-and-lim-x-to-c-gx-0-then-lim-x-to-cgxfx/1755164#1755164

Comment: $g(x)$ is bounded on the set $A$ if there is an $M>0$, finite, so that $|g(x)| \leq M$, for every $x$ in $A$.

Comment: essentially $ \lim f(x)g(x) \iff  \lim f(x)  \lim g(x)$ does not hold if not both limits exist

Comment: What does g is bounded imply.... Suppose it were not.  Suppose f(x) = x and g(x) = 1/x then g(x) is not bounded, and  $\lim x\to0 f(x)g(x) = 1$

Comment: my teacher says that i should use squeeze theorem to solve this problem. I am not sure what he means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is bounded, it means that $|g(x)|<c$ for some $c$, for all $x$. Now
$$
0\leq|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|\,|g(x)|\leq c|f(x)|.
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, we have $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$, and so by the squeeze theorem 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)g(x)=0. 
$$

Comment: 0≤ |f(x)g(x)|= |f(x)| |g(x)|≤  c|f(x)|. Sorry but i don't get it here, how can we have this one. Why 0≤ |f(x)g(x)|. We just know limf(x)=0

Comment: @phuongpham the absolute value of $a$ is always bigger or equal to $0$, so you always have $\lvert a\rvert\geq 0$